# Python logger `RotatingFileHandler` failing under Windows

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to use the `RotatingFileHandler` handler to manage potentially long logfiles for a Python project running under Windows. I have found that the log file rotation works fine when run using the IDLE interpreter (on a Windows PC) but fails with a WindowsError exception when run from the Windows command prompt.

Here is an example code that shows the problem -

```
import logging, logging.handlers
import datetime
import time

mainlogfile = 'fred.log'
logging_level = logging.DEBUG
logging_rotate_time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

logger = logging.getLogger('Main_Logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(mainlogfile, backupCount=7)
handler.setLevel(logging_level)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)      
logger.addHandler(handler)

next_rotate = datetime.datetime.now() + logging_rotate_time

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    logger.info('Tick ')
    n = datetime.datetime.now()
    if n>next_rotate:
        logger.info('Rotating logfile')
        handler.doRollover()
        logger.info('Succesfully rotated logfile')
        next_rotate = next_rotate + logging_rotate_time
        logger.info('Next logfile rotate at '+ str(next_rotate))
```

When I run this in the IDLE interpreter, it works fine and the log file `fred.log` is rotated every minute producing `fred.log.1, fred.log.2` etc. with contents such as -

```
2018-12-10 12:24:40,269 INFO Succesfully rotated logfile
2018-12-10 12:24:40,269 INFO Next logfile rotate at 2018-12-10 12:25:40.182000
2018-12-10 12:24:45,269 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:24:50,269 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:24:55,269 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:00,267 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:05,267 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:10,266 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:15,266 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:20,266 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:25,266 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:30,265 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:35,265 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:40,263 INFO Tick 
2018-12-10 12:25:40,263 INFO Rotating logfile
```

However, when run in a command prompt it fails on the first rotate attempt -

```
C:\> python try10.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try10.py", line 29, in <module>
    handler.doRollover()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 142, in doRollover
    os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

I have searched and found that there *are* problems under Windows when trying to close or rename log files that are in use by another Python process but I can't see how that is relevant to my simple example. I have tried calling `handler.flush()` and `handler.close()` before `handler.doRollover()` but this did not change the behavior.

My questions are -

- Why is the exception raised when run at the command prompt but not under IDLE?
- Is there any changes I can make to the code to allow it to run at the Windows command prompt

Comment: If this is the only code running in the process, then it's likely some other process is trying to access the file, but it could also be an anti-malware DLL injected in the current process. Bear in mind that this error message is misleading, "Another process" can in fact be the current process. Shared data access is per-open, not per-process. The Windows shared-access model is for read (execute), write (append), and delete (rename) access. All opens have to cooperate on how data access is shared among them.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for the input. It may be that `RotatingFileHandler` just doesn't work in a Windows environment because of these file-access differences? I have not found any other similar reports or work-arounds yet though

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code of the `doRollover()` method in the `logging.handlers` module, it can be seen that the exception above is being raised when `doRollover` tries to rename the log-file `fred.log` to `fred.log.1` using `os.rename()`. Trying to rename an open file like this will cause the exception under Windows, although earlier in the `doRollover()` method the open logfile should have been closed. Since my program as stands always fails in Windows console it looks like the logfile is not being properly closed. In the IDLE interpreter, it seems that file i/o is done differently than the console (via sockets as described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html?highlight=idle#idle-console-differences)) so maybe that this is what allows the code to run there.

Given that in order to allow `doRollover()` to rename the logfile, it has to be closed first and I discovered that this can be forced by temporarily removing the handler from the logger while doing the rollover - like this -

```
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    logger.info('Tick ')
    n = datetime.datetime.now()
    if n>next_rotate:
        logger.info('Rotating logfile')

        logger.removeHandler(handler)      
        handler.doRollover()        
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        logger.info('Succesfully rotated logfile')
        next_rotate = next_rotate + logging_rotate_time
        logger.info('Next logfile rotate at '+ str(next_rotate))
```

With these mods the code works fine and the log file `fred.log` is rotated every minute producing `fred.log.1`, `fred.log.2` etc. as expected

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, and it's clear in the [2.7 code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L121) that the stream is closed before renaming it. I think it's related to anti-malware (DLL injection or file-system filter driver) that's keeping a separate handle for the file open without delete/rename sharing. I'd test this by temporarily modifying the code in handlers.py to wait a second via `time.sleep(1)` right after the `self.stream.close()` call.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, I think you're correct  re. the 2.7 code. I jumped to conclusions there, so I have edited my 'answer' post to downgrade the certainty level. I will try the code mod you suggest.

Comment: how long did it take you to figure this out??  this is one jacked up problem with Windoze...  thanks for the ammo!